# Look down an unsorted list to find a greater than or equals value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a list of non-sorted quantity in column `A` and their corresponding values in column `B`.

I need a non-array Excel formula that returns the first value that is `greater than or equals to` the input quantity.

For e.g. :

`Minimum Qty: 6`

Scenario 1:

[image]

`Output Value: B`

Scenario 2:

[image]

`Output Value: B`

Scenario 3:

[image]

`Output Value: B`

Scenario 4:

[image]

`Output Value: Nil`

So far I've attempted `Index/Match` formulas but only the `small than or equal to` seem to work. `greater than or equals to` doesn't seem to work for a unsorted list.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps using `INDEX`, `AGGREGATE`, `ROW` and `IFERROR`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(B2:B4,AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A1:A3)/(A2:A4>=E3),1)),"Nil")
```

Breaking the key part `AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A1:A3)/(A2:A4>=E3),1)` down, using Scenario 1:

1. `ROW(A1:A3)/(A2:A4>=E3)`: this is `{1;2;3}/{2;6;3}>=6`.
2. `{2;6;3}>=6` evaluates to `{FALSE;TRUE;FALSE}`.
3. `{1;2;3}/{FALSE;TRUE;FALSE}` evaluates to `{#DIV/0!;2;#DIV/0!}`.
4. The first argument of AGGREGATE - `15` - means we are using the `SMALL` functionality.
5. The second argument of AGGREGATE - `6` - means that errors are ignored.
6. The last argument of AGGREGATE - `1` - corresponds to the 2nd (`k`) argument of `SMALL`, i.e. `SMALL(array, k)`.
7. So ignoring errors, `SMALL({#DIV/0!;2;#DIV/0!}, 1)` = `2`.
8. And similarly for the other scenarios:

   - Scenario 2: `SMALL({#DIV/0!;2;3}, 1)` = `2`.
   - Scenario 3: `SMALL({#DIV/0!;2;#DIV/0!}, 1)` = `2`.
   - Scenario 4: `SMALL({#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!;#DIV/0!}, 1)` throws a `#NUM!` error, so the `IFERROR` returns `Nil`.

**Scenario 1:**

[image]

**Scenario 2:**

[image]

**Scenario 3:**

[image]

**Scenario 4:**

[image]

Comment: It works! But don't quite understand what you did here with `AGGREGATE(15,6,ROW(A1:A3)/(A2:A4>=E3),1)`? Could you elaborate here a little more?

Answer (score 2):

Also You can use an array formula with `INDEX` and `MATCH` like this -

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($B$2:$B$4, MATCH(TRUE, $A$2:$A$4>=E3,0)), "Nil")
```

Use <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> to execute.